# How to code button to hide a range of cells?

Tags: vba, range, row, hidden

I am trying to create buttons that imitate the nature of nested rows, where when clicked, will hide the indented columns below it. I previously targeted a specific range of rows for each button, but as my company will attempt to add rows in the future, I want the code to continue to run properly regardless of where in the sheet the new row is added. Below is the code that I used:

```
Sub aButton()
    With Rows("1:22")
        If .Hidden Then
            .Hidden = False
        Else
            .Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

My attempted work around is to make a hidden column with A, B, C values per row to identify which range of rows go together. I want to be able to target all rows with "A" in column G, and use those values as my range in my existing code.

**Can you help?**

Comment: Have you looked into row groupings? That's built in to Excel. https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2013/groups-and-subtotals/1/

Comment: You can even record a macro to give you a start on how to code it.

Comment: braX - I'd like to do groupings but have the top row appear as the drop down, in contrast to your link. Is it possible to change the orientation of the grouping to allow that?